Trying to get a MS refresh token using fiddler for PowerShell authentication
We are using some old PowerShell script which is using a refresh token. It was working fine on the old server, but we try to migrate this script to another server. On this new server we need once a refresh token. How can I get the refresh token of a specific user account for login page of Exchange (https://outlook.office365.com)? In the technical documentation of this solution I read that I need to do it by fiddler, but I dont see the refresh token in the response header.
See below the powershell script which needs the refresh token:
$refresh_token_securestring = Get-Content "F:\scripts\PowerBI\ExchangeOnlineRefreshAccessToken.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString

$refresh_token_BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($refresh_token_securestring)
$refresh_token = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($refresh_token_BSTR)
Remove-Variable refresh_token_securestring
Remove-Variable refresh_token_BSTR

# Request Access token with refresh token 

$resourceID = "https://outlook.office365.com"
$tenant_id = "MyTenantGuid"
$clientId = "MyClientIdGuid"
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant_id}/oauth2/token"
$body = @{grant_type='refresh_token';resource=$resourceID;client_id=$client_id;refresh_token=$refresh_token}
$tokenresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body

